Nuxt 3 Latest: fsevents error while running via yarn dev
I was initiating a new project for a website using nuxt 3 via nuxt init. After I initiate it, i try to run it via yarn run dev (I choose yarn as my package manager). But after I run the said command, the error pops up while others are green.

When I try to run it via localhost:3000, I can able to see the localhost but it returns an error 503.

I try to resolve this matter wit this issue but still no luck.
Here's my details on my local machine:

Macbook M2 Pro
Yarn v1.22.22
Nuxt 3.11.2
Nitro 2.9.6
node v21.5.0

nuxt.config.ts
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  devtools: { enabled: true },

  vite: {
    optimizeDeps: { exclude: ["fsevents"] },
  },

  $production: {
    routeRules: {
      '/**': { isr: true }
    }
  },
  
  $development: {
    //
  }
})

package.json
{
  "name": "nuxt-app",
  "private": true,
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "nuxt build",
    "dev": "nuxt dev",
    "generate": "nuxt generate",
    "preview": "nuxt preview",
    "postinstall": "nuxt prepare"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "nuxt": "^3.11.2",
    "vue": "^3.4.27",
    "vue-router": "^4.3.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {}
}

.env
NUXT_PUBLIC_BASE_URL="http://localhost:3000"
#NUXT_PUBLIC_API_BASE="http://localhost:8000/api"

.zshrc if this helps:
# If you come from bash you might have to change your $PATH.
export PATH=$HOME/bin:/usr/local/bin:$PATH
export PATH=$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH
# export PATH=/usr/local/git/bin:/usr/local/bin:$PATH
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/git/bin:/usr/local/bin
export PATH=node_modules/.bin:$PATH # I enable this to run nuxt command
export PATH=$HOME/.composer/vendor/bin:$PATH

# Path to your oh-my-zsh installation.
export ZSH="$HOME/.oh-my-zsh"

# Set name of the theme to load --- if set to "random", it will
# load a random theme each time oh-my-zsh is loaded, in which case,
# to know which specific one was loaded, run: echo $RANDOM_THEME
# See https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/wiki/Themes
ZSH_THEME="agnoster"

# Set list of themes to pick from when loading at random
# Setting this variable when ZSH_THEME=random will cause zsh to load
# a theme from this variable instead of looking in $ZSH/themes/
# If set to an empty array, this variable will have no effect.
# ZSH_THEME_RANDOM_CANDIDATES=( "robbyrussell" "agnoster" )

# Uncomment the following line to use case-sensitive completion.
# CASE_SENSITIVE="true"

# Uncomment the following line to use hyphen-insensitive completion.
# Case-sensitive completion must be off. _ and - will be interchangeable.
# HYPHEN_INSENSITIVE="true"

# Uncomment one of the following lines to change the auto-update behavior
# zstyle ':omz:update' mode disabled  # disable automatic updates
# zstyle ':omz:update' mode auto      # update automatically without asking
# zstyle ':omz:update' mode reminder  # just remind me to update when it's time

# Uncomment the following line to change how often to auto-update (in days).
# zstyle ':omz:update' frequency 13

# Uncomment the following line if pasting URLs and other text is messed up.
# DISABLE_MAGIC_FUNCTIONS="true"

# Uncomment the following line to disable colors in ls.
# DISABLE_LS_COLORS="true"

# Uncomment the following line to disable auto-setting terminal title.
# DISABLE_AUTO_TITLE="true"

# Uncomment the following line to enable command auto-correction.
# ENABLE_CORRECTION="true"

# Uncomment the following line to display red dots whilst waiting for completion.
# You can also set it to another string to have that shown instead of the default red dots.
# e.g. COMPLETION_WAITING_DOTS="%F{yellow}waiting...%f"
# Caution: this setting can cause issues with multiline prompts in zsh < 5.7.1 (see #5765)
# COMPLETION_WAITING_DOTS="true"

# Uncomment the following line if you want to disable marking untracked files
# under VCS as dirty. This makes repository status check for large repositories
# much, much faster.
# DISABLE_UNTRACKED_FILES_DIRTY="true"

# Uncomment the following line if you want to change the command execution time
# stamp shown in the history command output.
# You can set one of the optional three formats:
# "mm/dd/yyyy"|"dd.mm.yyyy"|"yyyy-mm-dd"
# or set a custom format using the strftime function format specifications,
# see 'man strftime' for details.
# HIST_STAMPS="mm/dd/yyyy"

# Would you like to use another custom folder than $ZSH/custom?
# ZSH_CUSTOM=/path/to/new-custom-folder

# Which plugins would you like to load?
# Standard plugins can be found in $ZSH/plugins/
# Custom plugins may be added to $ZSH_CUSTOM/plugins/
# Example format: plugins=(rails git textmate ruby lighthouse)
# Add wisely, as too many plugins slow down shell startup.
plugins=(battery dnf emotty emoji git git-auto-fetch git-flow laravel mix npm nvm sudo systemadmin systemd themes ubuntu vscode wp-cli yarn)

source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh

# User configuration

# export MANPATH="/usr/local/man:$MANPATH"

# You may need to manually set your language environment
# export LANG=en_US.UTF-8

# Preferred editor for local and remote sessions
# if [[ -n $SSH_CONNECTION ]]; then
#   export EDITOR='vim'
# else
#   export EDITOR='mvim'
# fi

# Compilation flags
# export ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64"

# Set personal aliases, overriding those provided by oh-my-zsh libs,
# plugins, and themes. Aliases can be placed here, though oh-my-zsh
# users are encouraged to define aliases within the ZSH_CUSTOM folder.
# For a full list of active aliases, run `alias`.
#
# Example aliases
# alias zshconfig="mate ~/.zshrc"
# alias ohmyzsh="mate ~/.oh-my-zsh"

alias lrvl.fll.srv='composer dumpautoload -o && composer dump && php artisan cache:clear && php artisan route:clear && php artisan config:clear && php artisan config:cache && php artisan optimize:clear && composer dump-autoload && php artisan serve'
alias lrvl.srv='php artisan serve'
alias lrvl='php artisan'
alias yrn.dv='yarn dev'
alias yrn.srv='yarn serve'
alias yrn.strt='yarn start'
alias yrn.bld='yarn build'
alias yrn.gnrt='yarn generate'
alias yrn.rn='yarn run'
alias yrn.i='yarn install'
alias yrn.a='yarn add'
alias yrn.rm='yarn remove'
alias yrn='yarn'
alias npm='npm'
alias npm.dv='npm run dev'
alias npm.srv='npm run serve'
alias npm.wtch='npm run watch'
alias nuxi='npx nuxi'
alias g='git'
alias g.a='git add'
alias g.b='git branch'
alias g.c='git commit -m'
alias g.co='git checkout'
alias g.d='git diff'
alias g.f='git fetch'
alias g.i='git init'
alias g.m='git merge'
alias g.pll='git pull'
alias g.psh='git push'
alias g.s='git status'
alias g.cl='git clone'
alias g.st='git stash'
alias g.f='git flow'
alias sail='vendor/bin/sail'
alias sl='sail'
alias sl.srv='sail artisan serve'
alias sl.art='sail artisan'

# Homebrew
export PATH="/opt/homebrew/bin:$PATH"

# thefuck
export PATH="$PATH:~/.local/bin/"
eval $(thefuck --alias)
# You can use whatever you want as an alias, like for Mondays:
eval $(thefuck --alias FUCK)

export PATH="$HOME/.yarn/bin:$HOME/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/.bin:$PATH"

# Powerline Configuration
if [ -f /usr/share/powerline/bindings/bash/powerline.sh ]; then
  powerline-daemon -q
  POWERLINE_BASH_CONTINUATION=1
  POWERLINE_BASH_SELECT=1
  source /usr/share/powerline/bindings/bash/powerline.sh
fi

# export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
#   [ -s "/opt/homebrew/opt/nvm/nvm.sh" ] && \. "/opt/homebrew/opt/nvm/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm
#   [ -s "/opt/homebrew/opt/nvm/etc/bash_completion.d/nvm" ] && \. "/opt/homebrew/opt/nvm/etc/bash_completion.d/nvm"  # This loads nvm bash_completionexport PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/bison/bin:$PATH"
export NVM_DIR="$([ -z "${XDG_CONFIG_HOME-}" ] && printf %s "${HOME}/.nvm" || printf %s "${XDG_CONFIG_HOME}/nvm")"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" # This loads nvm

export LDFLAGS="-L/opt/homebrew/opt/bison/lib"
export LDFLAGS="-L/opt/homebrew/opt/curl/lib"
export CPPFLAGS="-I/opt/homebrew/opt/curl/include"
export PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/file-formula/bin:$PATH"
export PATH="/opt/homebrew/sbin:$PATH"
export PATH="/opt/homebrew/sbin:$PATH"
export PATH="/usr/local/sbin:$PATH"
export PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/curl/bin:$PATH"
export PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/ruby/bin:$PATH"
export LDFLAGS="-L/opt/homebrew/opt/ruby/lib"
export CPPFLAGS="-I/opt/homebrew/opt/ruby/include"
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/ruby/lib/pkgconfig"


# bun completions
[ -s "/Users/noelc/.bun/_bun" ] && source "/Users/noelc/.bun/_bun"

# bun
export BUN_INSTALL="$HOME/.bun"
export PATH="$BUN_INSTALL/bin:$PATH"
export VOLTA_HOME="$HOME/.volta"
export PATH="$VOLTA_HOME/bin:$PATH"
export PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/curl/bin:$PATH"

export PYENV_ROOT="$HOME/.pyenv"
[[ -d $PYENV_ROOT/bin ]] && export PATH="$PYENV_ROOT/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(pyenv init -)"

hope the details helps and any solution, suggestions and guidance is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Can you try with the stable even LTS version of node aka v20?

I am also not sure that you can write #NUXT_PUBLIC_API_BASE, maybe try to remove this one.

Maybe it's a core pack issue? Make sure that this one is enabled for yarn. Otherwise you could maybe give a try to npx nuxi@latest init <project-name> because it is maybe an issue with nuxt init.

@kissu I tried both of your suggestions and do the last one with npx nuxi@latest init <project-name> --force but still has the error
maybe it's a core pack issue, since most of my other nuxt projects runs smoothly except the newly created one
I also file this to the nuxt repository here just in case it is really a core pack issue: https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt/issues/27500

@kissu i wanna also post the logs during my installation process, kindly please look at the latest update of the post on my issue in nuxt repository: https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt/issues/27500, since I cant post image in the comment and cant edit the post anymore, thanks for the help man

OP achieved to have a working solution with the following as explained here:

Node v18.12.0
Yarn 1.22.19
cleaning every cache possible


Another thing to note is that OP uses Windows + might have some inconsistency in their yarn global configuration because the whole thing works perfectly with NPM.
Considering the amount of time that it might take, OP decided to move on with the given config above (that works) rather than dealing with troubleshooting yarn or using another package manager.

thanks for this @kissu, I didn't look up at this thread after we resolve this. I appreciate it a lot.
